# How to type 2-nd order tensor in latex?

Tags: tensor

I am a new user of latex. I have been learning to type in some math equations in latex. Does anybody know how to type 2-nd order tensor in latex with double arrows above the letter? And what package should I use? The following picture is an example of what I want to have.
[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[b]{esvect}
\newcommand{\VV}[1] {\vv{\vv{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \VV{T} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be this too can be a possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\huge \overrightarrow{\overrightarrow{T}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should load the `old-arrows`package, for the arrow tips not to overlap.